# $ 0 = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{\ln(n)} \implies Re(s) \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, exponential-sum

Define $f(s)$ as

$$ f(s) = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{\ln(n)}$$

where we take the upper complex plane as everywhere analytic.

Notice this is an antiderivative of the Riemann Zeta function, hence there is a log branch.
But like i said we take the upper complex plane as everywhere analytic, in other words we take the branch cut at the reals $<1$.

Now it appears that

$$f(s) = 0$$

implies that the real part of $s$ is smaller or equal than $1/2$ :

$Re(s) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Is this true ?

I tried the following

Let $Re(s) > 0$ and

$$ f_k(s) = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{k} \frac{n^{-s}}{\ln(n)}$$

And then solving

$$f_k(s) = 0$$

and assuming

$$ \lim_k f_k(s) = f(s) = 0$$
for the complex values $s$ ($Re(s) > 0$) that give zero's.

And then numerically solve for that.

Not sure if that is a good and valid way.

****MAIN question**** :

$$ 0 = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{-s}}{\ln(n)} \implies^{??} Re(s) \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Can you expand on "it appears that"?

Comment: @sku if my computations are correct, I was not able to find a counterexample.

Comment: how do you define $f(s)$ when $\Re s <1$ as the series doesn't converge; $f_k$ grows like $\frac{k^{1-\sigma}}{\log k}$ for fixed $s$ and $k$ large enough so $|f_k(s)| \to \infty, k \to \infty$ if $\Re s <1$

Comment: also note that even on $\Re s >1$ we have $-f'=\zeta-1$ so $f$ is not quite an antiderivative of $\zeta$ and I think it won't be very hard to prove that $f$ has many zeroes with $\Re s >1$

Comment: Well we have that constant of integration... @Conrad

Comment: @Conrad feel free to show us !

Comment: the point still stands that on $\Re s <1$ the definition of $f$ doesn't really have much to do with the Dirichlet partial sums and the only place where the Dirichlet series is valid is on $\Re s >1$; as a general principle Dirichlet series have many zeroes in their half plane of convergence unless there is a reason not have them and here I see no reason for that - by quasiperiodicity, you can show that near $\Re s =1$ you have a large image whose closure contains $0$

Comment: hmm I need to think about that. Not familiar with that quasiperiodicity argument.
maybe there are no zero's in the strip $1/2 <\Re(s) < 1$.

Comment: @Conrad Yes my arguments and computations are not formal. But I got some imo "hints". The theory of Truncated and asymptotic sums etc should relate. 
And ofcourse analytic continuation would be nice to make things formal. Or a simple counterexample.

Comment: The asymptotic behavior of the partials above for $\Re s <1$ is well known and for fixed $s$ they grow to infinity with $n$ so they won't have zeroes hence you cannot really investigate the zeroes that way for $\Re s<1$

Comment: For Dirichlet series in the domain of absolute convergence one should assume that they take all allowed values infinitely many times so if $0$ is not obviously excluded (eg product representation or closure image - which is known by Bohr results- not containing it) then it is safe to assume there will be infinitely many; for important series like say Riemann Hurwitz one except at $a=1/2,1$ when you get eta and zeta, it was proved in literature that they vanish infinitely many times in $\Re s>1$ so the burden of proof is to back up any claim about zeroes of Dirichlet series against the expected

Comment: @Conrad for almost all dirichlet series probably. But this one is close to the Riemann Zeta and the limit goes to $1$. I think it is safe to say for $\Re(s) > 2$ we have no zero's due to the convergeance speed to $1$.  I admit, I think this function is " special ".

Comment: The Riemann Hurwitz function at say $.99999999$ is also close to RZ and still has tons of zeroes as does the series with log n in the numerator ($\zeta'$ series)

Comment: @Conrad ofcourse the zeta derivative has all its zero's to the right of $\Re(s) = 1/2$, and you know very well why. Notice the "1" dropped by taking the derivative too.